# Quickblox Delete Dialogs on both sides of 1-to-1 chat IOS

Tags: ios, quickblox

I need some help completely deleting dialogs for 1-to-1 chats. I can delete the currently logged in user's dialog but I also want to delete the dialog for the other person in the 1-to-1 chat.

I've got round this by creating a custom message and sending it to the other user in the dialog when the first user deletes it on their side. This contains the dialog id and is then deleted when the other user logs into the app.

It seems inefficient. If the user has hundreds of 1-to-1 dialogs then I will have to send hundreds of messages to delete them on both sides.

Is this the only way to delete dialogs completely?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you can delete a dialog only fro yourself, your opponent still will be able to see this dialog.

This is the right way to do it. It's odd if this request also will delete a dialog to all users.

Your way is actually right to do it, no other ways for now.